# printing all data of scrollable JTable

Tags: java, swing, printing

i'm trying to print all the content of JPanel but i'm not able to print all content of scrollable JTable.I can print but not able to print the all data of Scrollable Jtable."Problem of printing all data not more than that".Code of print

```
    private void Printers(){
         PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
         job.setJobName("jpanel");
         PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
                                  aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
                                  aset.add(new PrinterResolution(300, 300, 
         PrinterResolution.DPI));
                                   aset.add(DialogTypeSelection.NATIVE);
         job.setPrintable (new Printable() {    
         public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum){
         if (pageNum > 0){
               return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
         }

         Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
         g2.translate(pf.getImageableX()+10, pf.getImageableY()+10);
//       g2.scale(1, 1);
        jpanel.paint(g2);
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
        });
        boolean ok = job.printDialog();
         if (ok) {
          try {
              job.print();
          } catch (PrinterException ex) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Printing error "+ex);
          }

        }

    }
```

[image: Here is the image]

Comment: Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtable.html) for examples.

Comment: I try from oracle but not understand

Comment: it coudn't be myTable.paint(g2); instead of jpanel.paint(g2);, because output talks about JPanels view :-)

Comment: yep.but all component are inside JPanel...so i want to print Jpanel with scrollable table..You can see at Picture i uploaded